# How to use the trapezoidal rule to approximate this integral?

Tags: integration

I have a question where I need to approximate the arc length of 
$y = $$\sqrt{x}$ in between x = 0 and x = 4 using numerical integration. I've managed to get the expression for the arc length:

$$ \int \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{4x}\,}\,\mathrm{d}x $$

but I'm not sure how to numerically integrate this using either the trapezoidal or Simpson's rule in order to get an approximation of the arc length. I can see using either that I can't start at x = 0 because it would be undefined there, would I need to start at something like x = 0.1?

This is what I've managed to come up with so far:

0.5 [f(0.1) + 2f(1) + 2f(2) + 2f(3) + f(4)] =
$0.5 [$$\sqrt{3.5}$ $+ 2$$\sqrt{2}$ $+ 2$$\sqrt{1.5}$ $+ 2$$\sqrt{4/3}$$+ 2$$\sqrt{5/4}$]
= 5.288090313, which I've rounded off to 5.3

Comment: Are you permitted to use a spread sheet such as Excel? You could start at $0.1$ and use increments of $0.1$ without much difficulty.

Comment: We're allowed to use graphing software, but I'm interested in knowing how to do it this way as we won't have that type of software available in exams.

Comment: In order to use the trapezoid rule, the value of $h$ must be constant. If you let $x_0=0.1$ and want to use $h=1$, then you need to use $1.1,\,2.1\,,3.1,\,4.1$. If you want better accuracy, use $0.01,\,1.01\,,2.01\,,3.01,\,4.01$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we have:

$$\mathscr{I}:=\int_0^4\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\int_0^4\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4x}}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^4\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{x}}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Substitute:

$$\text{u}=\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{x}}\tag2$$

So, we get:

$$\mathscr{I}=-\int_\infty^\frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}\frac{\text{u}^2}{\left(\text{u}^2-4\right)^2}\space\text{d}\text{u}=-\left\{\int_\infty^\frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}\frac{1}{\text{u}^2-4}\space\text{d}\text{u}+4\int_\infty^\frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}\frac{1}{\left(\text{u}^2-4\right)^2}\space\text{d}\text{u}\right\}\tag3$$

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the singularity by substituting $x = t^2$, the integral then becomes:

$$\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{4t^2 +1}dt$$